# Cannot port forward from 2 routers

Tags: router, port-forwarding

Some days ago my isp has installed a new router and now i have both of them, the normal one connected to the isp(new one), i tried port forwarding on the old router and on the new router but nothing seems to work.

The old one is a Dir-809 D-Link
And the new one is a HG8121H Huawei

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using 1 or both routers at the same time, and why the change? (It could be that your ISP is moving to Carrier Grade NAT,in which case you are out of luck, but it could also be that you need to reconfigure the WAN interface on the internal router and map the port from external router to internal router. You might also need to disable NAT and change routing on the internal router - all this depends on your setup and protocols in use.

Answer (score 2):

Make your D-Link act more like a switch.

Example steps might be:

1. Turn off the DHCP server on the D-Link
2. Maybe instruct your ISPs router to [reserve an address](http://www.dlink.cc/tag/dhcp-reservation) for your D-Link so that nothing else will take it
3. Give the D-Link a valid address in the range offered by the ISP router
4. Put tape over the WAN port on the D-Link, or repurpose it as a LAN port if that's an option in the settings

Comment: Cough cough... Dmz to the second router